# Unable to get storage account container details

Tags: azure, powershell, storage

Is there a way to get the storage account container details in Azure when private endpoint is enabled?

When i am trying to use `get-azcontainer -name -context`

I get an error `saying this is not an authorised operation`. However when i remove the private endpoint and enable public access. I am able to do so.

Hence, unable to figure out if there is any other way to achieve this

Tried using `get-azcontainer`. It didn't work as expected.

Request your help

Answer (score 0):

Private endpoint means it is created with the help of VNet-Subnet.

So, you have to access the Storage account from the Virtual Machines connected to that Subnet added in your Storage Account > Networking > Vnet - Subnet which is linked with that Private Endpoint.

Reference: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal) of Azure Storage Account using Private Link